# What do I specify as the "target folder" parameter to ClientBuildManager constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, pre-compilation

I'd like to experiment with the fourth parameter of [ClientBuildManager class constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150256) that lets me specify the compilation options. The problem is I have to provide the third parameter that specifies the "target folder".

Previously I used the [two-paremeters constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150254) like this:

```
VirtualDirectory dir = ...;
using( var buildManager = new ClientBuildManager( dir.Path, dir.PhysicalPath ) ) {
     buildManager.PrecompileApplication();
}
```

and it worked okay - the two parameters are quite obvious.

I have no idea where to get the third "target folder" parameter.

How do I obtain the value that can be passed as the third "target folder" parameter so that precompilation works as before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **pass null** for the TargetFolder if you just want to ["Compiling an Application in Place"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  If you pass a valid folder for TargetFolder you will be ["Compiling an Application for Deployment"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).